# Create new manufcaturer from query in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, sql, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

I'm using knowbandmarketplace module in a prestashop 1.7 shop to allow users to add their own product. There are some basic infos such as EAN, Title, etc...i need to edit this code

```
<input type="text" class="kb-inpfield" name="manu" value="{$manu|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" maxlength="12" />
  <select name="id_manufacturer" class="kb-inpselect">
    <option>{l s='Select Manufacturer' mod='kbmarketplace'}</option>                                                     
    {foreach $manufacturers as $manu}
     <option value="{$manu['id_manufacturer']|intval}" {if $manu['id_manufacturer'] == $id_manufacturer}selected="selected"{/if} >{$manu['name']|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</option>
    {/foreach}
  </select>
```

in order to allow users create their own manufacturer through the value written in text form (if it does not exists already in the dropdown list generated) just like they would normally do in back office's manufacturers and brands page.

Comment: What have you tried? Your problem description is rather vague.

Comment: I just tried to submit the value in the input area; i knew it would (obviously) not work. I'm totally new in prestashop theme/smarty development so i just have no idea how to implement this function

Comment: What exactly happened when you tried that? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: When i saved these information, all worked as it should have, except for this field; the value did not count as a new manufacturer entry. As i said, i need to let users create a new manufacturer from this field if they can't find the one they need in the list below.